# Swift 2 load image from url variable error

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, nsurl, loadimage

I have load_image function and works with

```
load_image("http://blabla.com/bla.png")
```

But when i add variable like this

```
 load_image(detailDesc2!)
```

gives this error

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

My codes here

ViewController table view selected codes. Here send detailDesc1 , and detailDesc 2 to DetailView Controller

```
  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let subcatVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Detail") as! DetailViewController
        subcatVC.detailDesc1 = self.arrayCategory[indexPath.row][API_PARAM_CAT_ID] as! String
        subcatVC.detailDesc2 = self.arrayCategory[indexPath.row][API_PARAM_CAT_IMAGE] as! String
        _ = UINavigationController(rootViewController: subcatVC)
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(subcatVC, animated: false)
    }
```

DetailViewController

```
   var detailDesc1:String?
    var detailDesc2:String?

    load_image(detailDesc2!)  // HERE GIVES ERROR
```

My load_image function

```
func load_image(urlString:String)
{
    let imgURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlString)!
    let request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: imgURL)

    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request){
        (data, response, error) -> Void in

        if (error == nil && data != nil)
        {
            func display_image()
            {
                self.imagetbig.image = UIImage(data: data!)
            }

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), display_image)
        }

    }

    task.resume()
}
```

Also when i add this codes success working label and textviews shows.

```
textbig.text = detailDesc1
textim.text = detailDesc2
```

Comment: Your urlString is nil. Check the detailDesc2-value before you pass it.

Comment: When do you call "load_image(detailDesc2!)" ?

Comment: Resolved guys thanks ! All Victor gives codes ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason your variable `detailDesc2` is `nil` and you force the unwrapping using the `!` telling the compiler that the variable always have a value when the variable was declared optional(it could be non-value). According to [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html):

> Trying to use ! to access a non-existent optional value triggers a runtime error. Always make sure that an optional contains a non-nil value before using ! to force-unwrap its value.

You can avoid the runtime error using [optional binding](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html), checking before use the variable like in the following way:

```
if let url = detailDesc2 {
    load_image(url)
}
```

As @LeoDabus recommend now in Swift 2, you can use too the [`guard`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html) statement that you can use like in the following way:

```
guard if let url = detailDesc2 else {
   return 
}

load_image(url)
```

According to [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html):

> A guard statement, like an if statement, executes statements depending on the Boolean value of an expression. You use a guard statement to require that a condition must be true in order for the code after the guard statement to be executed. Unlike an if statement, a guard statement always has an else clause—the code inside the else clause is executed if the condition is not true.

I hope this help you.

Comment: @SwiftDeveloper You're welcome, please accept the answer if it solve your question.

Comment: @Victor  Swift 2.0 guard let data = data where error == nil else { return }

Comment: @LeoDabus Yes you're right, `guard` is a syntactic sugar it can be used too.

Answer (score 0):

I expect `self.arrayCategory[indexPath.row][API_PARAM_CAT_IMAGE]` returns nil

You can check the variable before using:

```
if let imageUrl = detailDesc2 {
    load_image(imageUrl)
}
```